# Nginx. Issue to access redoc

Tags: django, docker

I have the Django project and trying to deploy it on server using docker and nginx.
There is no problem to deploy it and get access to required pages, but I can't get access to redoc page.
Nginx config is following ( default.conf):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /static/ {
        root /var/html/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /var/html/;
    }
    location /redoc/ {
        root /var/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/redoc.html;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.4
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  web:
    image:
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_value:/code/static/
      - media_value:/code/media/
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.3
    ports:
      - "80:80"

    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - static_value:/var/html/static/
      - media_value:/var/html/media/
      - .static/redoc.yaml:/var/html/redoc/redoc.yaml
      - .templates/redoc.html:/var/html/redoc/redoc.html

    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_value:
  media_value:
```

Could you, please, advice what is wrong is set up ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the path to the `redoc.html` within your `volumes`. If this html file is located inside the folder `templates`, that is next to the `docker-compose.yml`, instead of

```
      - .templates/redoc.html:/var/html/redoc/redoc.html
```

try

```
      - ./templates/redoc.html:/var/html/redoc/redoc.html
```

then access by going to `http://<ip-address>/redoc/` (with that slash at the end).